# ASP.NET MVC How can better filter my route?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have added a new route to my routing table:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
          "ModuleRoute", // Route name
          "Module/{href}", // URL with parameters
          new { controller = "Module", action = "GetHtml" }// Parameter defaults
      );
```

I need this route to match on the following url structure:

> /module/123abc.html

The problem is it also matches on this structure

> /module/Launch/123abc.html

Calling link :

```
    <%: Html.ActionLink("Launch", "Launch", new { href = item.Href })%>
```

How do I stop that from happening? I want he second structure to continue to be matched by the default route. I thought that because the number of parameters are different that this would not be a problem.

How can better filter my route to prevent this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure `Module/{href}` matches `module/Launch/123abc.html`? Doesn't sound right.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you're mapping to a specific `.html` file. could you expand on your use case for this? There may be a better way entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i agree with Max Toro, i've done some testing and that URL doesn't match `Module/{href}`.

This:

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("Launch", "Launch", new { href = item.Href })%>
```

is actually hitting the default route. You see this if you change the default route to the below (note the id is changed to `href`

```
 routes.MapRoute(
     "Default", // Route name
     "{controller}/{action}/{href}", // URL with parameters
     new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", href = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
 );
```

so, this proves it is falling through the first route since it gets a proper url (no querystrings)

what it is doing (when you have the usual default route with `id`) is that the `controller` and `action` are matched but the `id` isn't. This is OK - the route still matches but leaves off the `id`. All additional values, such as your `href` are appended as querystring parameters so you end up with:

```
module/Launch?href=123abc.html
```

The way to get around it is to add another route similar to the one above that uses `href` instead of `id`

something like:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
     "Launch",
     "Module/Launch/{href}",
     new { controller = "Module", action = "Launch", href = UrlParameter.Optional }
 );
```